# Using ActiveX dll Control in JSF page

Tags: javascript, jsf, dll, activex

I have an ActiveX DLL Control embedded in an html page which basically interact with the remote cloud API, this works perfectly fine.
Now I would like to embed the same ActiveX DLL control with in a JSF page. But it doesn’t work.

```html
<object id="AmiVoice" style="margin-left: 10px"
classid="clsid:5B0A35BB-C5EB-43C7-8A0E-1D85C1E122A3" width="75%"
codebase="AmiDsrc.dll" type='application/x-itst-ActiveX DLL'
height="32">
</object>
```

It is downloading and installing the ActiveX DLL, but When I am trying to invoke the ActiveX DLL  inside a javaScript function using 
`var code = AmiVoice.ExecuteCommand(command);`, nothing happens. But it works in HTML Page.

**If I use the same html  tag inside JSF will it work?**

**If yes, Can I refer to the ActiveX DLL control by its "id" just like as in html.**

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code here. Yes to the first question and *somehow* to the second

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to figure out the issue. In my jsf page I have used a <form> tag which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my queries. 
I had a `<form>` tag in my jsf page, and the `<object>` tag was placed inside it, which was causing the issue
Otherwise with myfaces.version =2.1.8 & mojarra.version=2.1.11 it works well.

If I use the same html tag inside JSF will it work? **YES**

If yes, Can I refer to the ActiveX DLL control by its "id" just like as in html. **YES**